# Cannot push to BitBucket Mercurial Repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

Hi I have an HG repository on bitbucket. The local repository I had got on a linux mint machine got messed up so I deleted the files and downloaded them again into the folder. When I try to synchronize my edited files in my local repository back to update the repository on bitbucket with TortoiseHG it says "abort:repository unrelated". How do I fix this?

Comment: Does `hg verify` report any issues? If it does, your repository may be corrupted, in which case it might be difficult to fix. The easiest solution might be just to re-clone.

Comment: I recloned the repository and just copied the files over that and it seems to have worked.